# Создание ImageList в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

**ImageList** как такового нет в **WPF**, так как это элемент из **WF**.
Мне нужно полностью перенести функционал **ImageList** в **WPF**.

Что пробовал:

1. Использовать **WindowsFormsHost**, но в **System.Windows.Forms.Integration** нет **ImageList**
2. Создать аналог собственноручно, но я не знаю всех возможностей **ImageList** и способов их реализаций.
3. Может ещё что-то пробовал, но сейчас не вспомню.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

---

**Дополнения:**

*В моём случае нужно именно бездумно перенести ImageList с WF на WPF, прожект не мой изначально и все его тонкости я не знаю, потому мне нужно, чтобы каждая функция или процедура данного элемента в точности дублировала оригинал.*

Comment: `Мне нужно полностью перенести функционал` - какой, этот `я не знаю всех возможностей ImageList`? Что вы хотите получить то? Картинки с галочками слева, или что? Скажите, какую задачу вы решаете.

Comment: `но я не знаю всех возможностей ImageList и способов их реализаций.` - а зачем вам знать все возможности какого-то стороннего софта? Думайте о своем, решайте конкретно свою задачу, а не бездумно переносите целиком контролы лишь потому, что они могут вам помочь. Так что забудьте про `ImageList` и опишите конкретно то, что вы решаете.

Comment: В моём случае нужно именно бездумно перенести **ImageList** с WF на WPF, прожект не мой изначально и все его тонкости я не знаю, потому мне нужно, чтобы каждая функция или процедура данного элемента в точности дублировала оригинал.

Comment: Мы можем помочь вам написать код _идиоматически_, то есть, так, как это принято писать на WPF. Дублировать все особенности класса из WinForms вряд ли кому-то будет интересно. Опишите лучше, какое поведение вам нужно, а мы скажем, как такое реализуется на WPF.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать матрицу из изображений, чтобы можно было например сделать так
`int imageIndex = this._ImageList.Images.IndexOfKey(image);`
`var blank = new Bitmap(this._ImageList.ImageSize.Width, this._ImageList.ImageSize.Height);`
`_ImageList.Images.Add("Blank", blank);`

Comment: Если нужна матрица, то в WPF есть `ItemsControl`, которому можно что угодно внутрь элемента засунуть. Хоть картинку, хоть текст, хоть паровоз с вагонами, отрисовывать он это будет на панели, которую ему так же можно задать, есть `UniformFrid`, если надо по колонкам и столбцам, есть даже `Canvas`, и еще куча разных панелей. Но по куску кода, который вы показали, непонятна суть задачи. Если вам нужен функционал Winforms, оставайтесь в WF, зачем вам сдался этот WPF? Принцип построения приложений в WPF более универсальный, и ни капельки не похож на формы. Если интересно, почитайте про MVVM в WPF.

Comment: Как человек, который когда-то слез с форм на WPF и пытался использовать подход к разработке в WPF из форм, скажу наверняка - это тупик, бесперспективняк, который родит вам неподдерживаемого (без бутылки) монстра. Поэтому советую вам начать учить WPF+MVVM сразу,  плюс привязки данных, плюс команды вместо обработчиков. Идеологически, в формах вы управляете интерфейсом, в WPF это плохая практика, сложная. В WPF интерфейс разрабатывается как самостоятельная боевая единица (в XAML). А остальной код в C# обеспечивает интерфейс данными, но не управляет им. Так работают привязки данных (`Binding`).

Comment: Ваша задача наверняка простая. Но делается она не так как вы себе представляете. А чтобы сделать, надо понять поведение, как это работает для пользователя приложения. Например: Раньше вы ездили по грязи на танке, напрямую, теперь у вас новая быстрая спортивная машина, но по грязи она едет хуже, а по трассе в объезд можно доехать быстрее, чем раньше напрямую срезая путь. Хотите по грязи и напрямую (это и есть суть вашего вопроса) - берите танк. Инструменты надо использовать по назначению.

Comment: MVVM я много раз читал и пытался понять что там да как, но так и не смог разобраться, в этой проблеме тоже пытался использовать.

Comment: По поводу создания своего аналога всё сложнее, есть программист, который сделал программу на WinForms, передомной поставили задачу полностью портировать её. С большей частью проблем я справился и порт готов, осталось только вот эта проблема, которая недаёт мне закончить проект. ImageList в этой программе используется крайне часто и надо понять весь его функционал именно в этой программе, а как известно всем и вся, разобраться в чужом коде без бутылки очень сложно впринципе. Сам проект уже полностью портирован и работает.